# scaling a circle to tangent two other circles (Adobe Illustrator)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

im trying to scale the red circle such that it tangents the two yellow circles exactly while also tangenting the blue circle at the bottom of the red circle.
[image: Text]
[image: Text]
i need a method that will guarantee that the red circle only just tangents the yellow circle, no gaps or intersections
im not going to zoom in until it looks about right because that will probably be

Comment: Depends on how pedantic your definition of things are. The first problem is that illustrator is unable to draw a true circle. So the answer is with some reservations on "perfect"

Comment: One thing's for sure, Illustrator is not AutoCad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your case is actually much easier than the "draw a circle tangential with 3 given circles" -problem taken from ancient geometry. Your constellation of the given circles is left-right symmetric. You know the point where the red circle touches the blue circle, so there's much less to be found.

[image]

I drew the other yellow circle as dashed, because it will be taken into the account automatically due the LR-symmetry. The radius of the blue circle is not needed; the bottom point is the only part of the blue circle which affects the result. I placed there my coordinate origin.

But R, the radius of the red circle must be calculated or found otherwise so that

- the red circle touches the blue circle just in my coordinate origin and
- the touching point P on the yellow circle exists.

The center Q of the wanted red circle is at distance R above the origin.

Finding R by calculating should be based on the known placement and radius of the yellow circle. Let S be the radius and let horizontal and vertical line segments a and b be the displacement of the centerpoint from my origin.

Elementary plane geometry calculations (see NOTE1) give the following formula for R:

R = 0,5((S^2)-(a^2)-(b^2))/(s-b)

I have tried it by setting in millimeters a=10, b=14 and S=30. The formula gives R=18,875 millimeters or as well the right diameter of the red circle is 37,75 mm.

[image]

In Inkscape it's easy to draw the test items due the well working snappings. I placed the yellow circle at the top left corner of the green 10 x 14 millimeters rectangle. The bottom point of the calculated red circle was placed to the bottom right corner of the rectangle. The red circle touches the yellow circle as expected.

**NOTE1:** Nothing flashy here, only Pythagorean theorem and the fact that the radiuses to the touching point P must be on the same line due the tangency. See the green triangle in the next image:

[image]

The triangle is rectangular. We can write S as the sum of the of the triangle hypotenuse and the radius R:

S = sqrt((a^2) + (R-b)^2) + R

Writing R out gives the formula.

**Some opinions**

1. It would be much easier to draw at first the red circle
2. The artwork wouldn't be by any means weaker if you simply scale the red circle visually with high zoom in.

Some people who can understand Archimedes and Apollonius may think the artwork quality totally differently. The artwork isn't the drawing, but the making of it. Here's something for them https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1861627/circle-tangent-to-three-circles And here's another, in more condensed form: https://facstaff.susqu.edu/brakke/rulerandcompass/39-threecircles.html

The linked cases are discussions of the ancient "draw a circle tangential with 3 given circles" -problem. Questioner's problem is a special case of it. Of course the linked general solutions can be adapted to this easier special case. I show it in the end of the answer. I guess it's close what you actually want. You said in a comment that you expect in first place drawing with auxiliary lines and snappings in a vector drawing program.

CAD programs allow drawing circles tangential with selected items. I have seen it's possible to select three circles, but the freebie I happen to have do not accept circles which cross each other. The result is "no solution exists". No idea does it work OK in commercial programs. The problem can also be hidden into advanced settings that I do not know well enough.

Snapping as a principle is not better than searching iteratively the right sizes and placements with high zoom-in eyeballing. Snappings are also iterative searches, but automatic ones. The ancient geometry doesn't make constructions with iterations.

**Solution by drawing only**

This applies the linked general solution. Because the constraints are  radically simplified the solution also is reduced to striking short. It starts by drawing a vertical radius (black line S) to the yellow circle:

[image]

The radius of the blue circle is not used to anything. Like above, only the bottom point of the blue circle is important. Next

- move the drawn radius to start from the bottom point of the blue circle
- draw a line (=green) between the center of the yellow circle and the top of the moved radius:

[image]

Rotate 90 degrees the green line. The point Q where the rotated line (=magenta) crosses the moved radius is the centerpoint of the wanted red circle:

[image]

At least in Inkscape the red circle snaps easily to the bottom of the blue circle when one draws it by holding Ctrl+Shift and starts from Q.

BTW I bet most of us would scratch one's head a while when trying to figure out why the solution works if they didn't know it's a shortened version of the linked more general case.

Comment: it looks very convincing but actually the circle created with this method ends up being very very slightly smaller than the circle it should create. shown in this extreme case : [link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/328356527893118976/1019879905799970886/unknown.png)

Comment: When a big length is subtracted from another big length small percentage errors can cause big percentage error to the difference. But the method as an idea fulfills the logic soundness requirements that Apollonius, Archimedes, etc... were after. Practical engineering needs math processes where the usefulness is at least checked in case of inaccurate numbers . Ancient geometry paid no attention to this. In my calculated formula-version one can easily analyze the sensitivity to inaccuracy. Qualitatively it's easy to see that the difference S-b in the denominator can cause big numerical errors.

Comment: okay yeah that makes sense, i guess adobe illustrator isn't up for the task i guess

Comment: Tell quantities a, b and S in your drawing method test. I'm interested the sensitivity.

Comment: i just made the yellow ones very large [view](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/328356527893118976/1020535469538287726/1663384998_92XTm_Untitled-1__3.13__RGBCPU_Outline_.mp4)

Answer (score 2):

Couple ways...

One of the easier....

Select the red circle. On the **Transform panel** (`Window > Transform`):

- Make certain the *bottom center* point is selected on the **9-point origin**
- Make certain the **Link** icon is depressed
- Then enter values in the `w` or `h` field

Below I merely held the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key down and tapped the `up` arrow on the keyboard. This causes the value in the field to increase by increments of 10. Once I got close, I let go of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and kept tapping up (increments of 1).

[image]

One could also use the `Distort & Transform` **Effect** to do basically the same thing. And you *could* use the **Scale Tool** but it's difficult to set the origin precisely with with that tool. And there *are* 3rd-party plug-ins out there, such as ColliderScribe, than help with stuff like this.

It's *not* possible to do this by dragging a Bounding Box handle, because you *can't* set the transform origin for the bounding box.

Comment: Why do you say the origin is hard to set? It snaps to points just like anything else. (Note there is a dreawing glitch in illustrator that depicts the origin slightly offset from where it is located)

Comment: Origin can be difficult with the Scale Tool because it requires the user to click to set the origin (yes you could configure guides and zoom in)... with transform or the effect, the 9-pt origin is based on the object itself.

Comment: i was hoping for something more geometric that uses snapping and "helper shapes" rather than trial and error

Comment: @Ravarcheon the problem is that because the beziers are not circles they wouldnt snap correctly anyway. But yes you can find the exact center its just a bit tricky since the problem is a bit tricky.

Comment: also why I mentioned ColliderScribe in my answer..

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach, just using smart guides and snapping (and no maths!). It doesn't involve scaling the red circle afterwards though, since there is no way (AFAIK) to get Illustrator to detect the collision point. I think this is probably as "exact" as it's possible to get using just Illustrator without any third party plugins. Also as others have mentioned, Illustrator can't actually create mathematically perfect circles, only Bézier approximations of a circle.

Anyway, here goes:

1. In Outline mode, draw two circles, one large and one small, set the strokes to none. The smaller of the two here will become the red circle as shown in your example.
2. Position the smaller circle such that it intersects with the edge of the larger circle.

[image]

3. Select both and rotate into position.

[image]

4. Drop two vertical guides such that they intersect with the centres of both circles.

[image]

5. Drop two horizontal guides such that they intersect with the top of the large circle, and the bottom of the small circle.

[image]

6. Draw a circle such that it intersects with the two horizontal guides.

[image]

7. Move the circle such that it intersects with the vertical centre guide of the smaller circle, and the top horizontal guide.

[image]

8. Select all, and copy and paste and reflect on the Y axis.
9. Move the copy such that it intersects with the original. You can delete the two centre circle duplicates at this point.

[image]

10. You can zoom in to check where the circles touch, they're not perfect, but as close as it's probably possible to get.
11. Exit outline mode, apply strokes as required. Rearrange the objects in the stack if necessary.

[image]

Comment: You actually drew an arbitary tangential red circle at first and then made a blue one which fits. As artistic drawing result it can well be OK if there's no reason to have certain predetermined blue and yellow circles. I have only suggested drawing the red circle at first, but you did it.

Comment: @user287001 Well actually I drew the yellow one first, but yeah!

Comment: sorry i cant use this because i'm creating the red circle last, the radius and center position of the red circle depend on the other 3 circles